# Linking a php file to a HTML file?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

On this site http://www.flatness.eu/test.html I have a link to a php file.

That file contains an art piece which is written in php.

The page contains layers of images which the user clicks to remove one by one until the page is empty.

Is it possible to make the last click on the php file link the user straight back to the html home page they started from?

Comment: Can you post your code here so it will be relevant to those who come across this later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The php file you link to is using jQuery to add a class called `houdini` to images that are hidden. You can change the click handler to count the amount of images left where the class isn't houdini, and then redirect the user.

```
$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
    $(".image").click(function() {     //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
      $(this).addClass("houdini");     //add the class to the clicked element

      if( $('.image:not(.houdini)').length == 1 )
      {
          // this is the last image, redirect user
          window.location = 'http://yourpageurl.com';
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Better than mine... But this looks at all images and cannot be used if there are images on page that should not count... But for this particular solution - this is simpler than mine. +1

Comment: thanks!!this worked, although it clicks back a little too early, say two clicks before it should?

Comment: Should that not be `.length == 0`? The redirect is after the last image is hidden, according to the question.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server side - it can't know when user clicked the last picture if you don't communicate with server on every click.

As in your code you add class to css via jquery to hide pictures, you can count how many elements have that class with $('.houdini').length and based on that you can invoke the redirect via javascript: window.location = "URL_HERE";

Easier from counting up is counting down - so you can start by making all images have some class like 'shown', and then on click do:

```
$(".image").on('click',function() {
  $(this)addClass('houdini').removeClass('shown');
  if ($('shown').length == 0) {
    window.location = 'http://www.flatness.eu/home.html';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in PHP: Trigger when empty:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit;
?>
```

edit:
You actually remove the pictures with js, so reload should be triggered by js as well!

```
  $(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
    $(".image").click(function() {     //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
      $(this).addClass("houdini");     //add the class to the clicked element
            if($('.houdini').length == $(".image").length)
            {
            window.location.href="http://www.example.com/";
            }  
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

link up with html code..

i guess you have written all the code in HTML then you just have mix your PHP code with HTML code.

like,

```
<?php
  //your php code
 ?>
```

or provide a form action in your page to provide the path of your home file.

Comment: What are you trying to say here?

Comment: just link up php code with script.. and provide header location in script to redirect where you want.. i had written in short.